# Different behavior of generators in python-2.7.12 and python-3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Generators behave differently in python2 and python3 for the code below.

```
def g1():
  for i in range(3):
    print("in g1: {}".format(i))
    yield i


def g2():
  for i in range(3):
    print("in g2: {}".format(i))
    yield 2*i


def g3(f1,f2):
  for (i,(x,y)) in enumerate(zip(f1,f2)):
    print("in g3: {} ---- {},{}".format(i,x,y))
    yield (x,y)

h1 = g1()
h2 = g2()

h3=g3(h1,h2)

print(list(h3))
```

Output of python2

```
in g1: 0
in g2: 0
in g1: 1
in g2: 1
in g1: 2
in g2: 2
in g3: 0 ---- 0,0
in g3: 1 ---- 1,2
in g3: 2 ---- 2,4
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4)]
```

Output of python3

```
in g1: 0
in g2: 0
in g3: 0 ---- 0,0
in g1: 1
in g2: 1
in g3: 1 ---- 1,2
in g1: 2
in g2: 2
in g3: 2 ---- 2,4
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4)]
```

Why does this happen? 
python3 behaviour is desired. Can this be achieved in python2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, `zip` is not lazy and returns a list, consuming its arguments completely. However, you can simulate Python 3 behavior with [`izip` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
from itertools import izip

...
for (i,(x,y)) in enumerate(izip(f1,f2)):
...
```

On 2.7.15, with `zip` changed to `izip`, the code outputs:

```
in g1: 0
in g2: 0
in g3: 0 ---- 0,0
in g1: 1
in g2: 1
in g3: 1 ---- 1,2
in g1: 2
in g2: 2
in g3: 2 ---- 2,4
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4)]
```